# Эффект размытия внутри диалогового окна Android

Tags: android

Всем привет, кто-нибудь знает, как реализовать такой динамический фон у диалогового окна?

[Пример](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-COujBdJebEU/U0EwhJkLxFI/AAAAAAAACdE/GX0G9ZDVTIY/w420-h747-no/dialog.jpg)

Comment: по моему это просто серый полупрозрачный ... могу ошибаться, скачайте переложение на комп посмотрите ресурсы

Answer (score 1):

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);

c API версии 14 не работает

с другой стороны - если надо размыть свою собственную activity - то способ есть. Заблюрить с 4.0 только чужое нельзя

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21052060